# Laravel contact form error: Expected response code 354 but got code "554", with message "554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients "

Tags: laravel

Hice una página web con formulario de contacto en Laravel.
Localmente con mailtrap, el formulario funciona perfecto, pero cuando lo envío online con el correo de Hostinger, recibo un error.
Investigué pero no encontré la solución.

Normalmente hago el formulario de contacto con Gmail, pero quería probar con otro correo.
En Gmail, lo que tengo que poner en **MAIL_USERNAME** y **MAIL_PASSWORD** es una "*contraseña de aplicación*", pero para mi sorpresa, el correo de Hostinger no ofrece esto.

No sé si tiene la culpa (la ausencia de esto, no Hostinger), pero de todos modos
¿Puede ayudarme alguien?

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.hostinger.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=(ejemplo@mail.com)
MAIL_PASSWORD=(contraseña)
MAIL_ENCRYPTATION =TLS
```

MailController

```
public function contact(Request $request){
  $inputData = $request->input();

  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Web::$validation['contact']['rules'], Web::$validation['contact']['messages']);

  if($validator->fails()){
    return redirect('/demo#contactar')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
  }else{
    $objDemo = (object) $inputData;

    Mail::to('example@mail.com')->send(new Contact($objDemo));

    return redirect()->route('mail.thx');
  }
}
```

Class Contact

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Contact extends Mailable{
  use Queueable, SerializesModels;

  public $data;

  public function __construct($inputData){
    $this->data = $inputData;
  }

  public function build(){
    $mail = $this->data->mail;
    $name = $this->data->name;
    $issue = "$name quiere contactar a alguien";
    return $this->view('mail.contact')
      ->from($mail, $name)
      ->subject($issue);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según el código fuente de Laravel, estos dos parámetros no son necesarios, solo si los exige el servidor de correo.

Extracto del código de Laravel encargado de administrar esta información:

```
    // Once we have the transport we will check for the presence of a username
    // and password. If we have it we will set the credentials on the Swift
    // transporter instance so that we'll properly authenticate delivery.
    if (isset($config['username'])) {
        $transport->setUsername($config['username']);

        $transport->setPassword($config['password']);
    }
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Mail/TransportManager.php#L40

En caso que no te funcione sin el usuario y contraseña, te sugiero que contactes al soporte técnico de dicho hosting, puesto que ya es una configuración específica que pueden requerir.

Comment: Mmm, pensé que eran obligatorios, gracias. Probare en sacarlos y si funciona me salvaste la vida jaja

Comment: @Archimak tienes que aprender a identificar el problema realmente, porque el mensaje de error dice una cosa, pero lo que estás preguntando es otra cosa. Yo respondí lo que estás preguntando.

Comment: Realmente pregunte por ayuda, no pregunte nada especifico, los puse en mi situación y eso... No se más que, que el error es al enviar el correo, nunca lo obtuve antes (Ya que normalmente trabajo con Gmail y no tengo problemas, eso aclaré)

Answer (score 0):

No hay una respuesta de manual para tu problema. El error que te sale (554 5.5.1) significa que intentaste enviar el correo** sin destinatarios válidos pero...** Qué se considera como un destinatario inválido?

- Casillas de correo sin dueño, inactivas, sin espacio (esto pasaba) ?  Todo lo contrario. Si el protocolo sirviera para validar casillas sería una mina de oro para los spammers.
- Direcciones que contienen caracteres inválidos? Si y no.

  - acorde al RFC 2821 cualquier string que pueda ser interpretado como tal localmente , seguido de un @ y un dominio , son un mail válido, incluyendo el uso de comillas como literales. "potus@gov.us"@yandex.ru es una dirección válida. [Lectura recomendada](https://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/)
  - Pero si el servidor dónde corres laravel utiliza postfix, Hay secuencias de escape que provocan un error que a su vez por un segundo error es atribuido a una causa que no corresponde
  - a lo anterior hay que sumar a los cientos de miles de intermediarios que quisieron ser más inteligentes que él rfc y rechazan correos válidos

Dicho todo lo anterior como está es una comedia de malentendidos, yo apostaría a que tú problema es de autenticación, básicamente porque distintos proveedores tienen distintos requisitos.  Los settings para aws, Gmail y sendgrid son -por ejemplo- incompatibles entre si

**Edit:**

Creo que puede ser útil explicar el tema de los settings incompatibles. Me refiero por ejemplo a que distintos proveedores de correo via SMTP no tienen ni de cerca un contrato de interfaz que norme puertos, campos o protocolos.

Comparando entre proveedores de SMTP, es decir teniendo siempre en el .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```

tenemos que algunos proveedores SMTP requieren enviar el remitente al instanciar el correo, poniendo en el .env

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=contacto@miproyecto.com
   MAIL_FROM_NAME='Nada menos que yo'

(¿Estabas poniendo esto en Hostinger?)

En el caso de gmail, las otras variables de entorno debieran ser

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_USERNAME=micorreo@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=miclave
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Y además habilitar el inicio de contraseña con apps no seguras en el panel de tu cuenta Google.

En el caso de Amazon SES, sería

```
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_USERNAME=AKIAAAAAAAAAXXXXXXXXXXXx
MAIL_PASSWORD=miclave_de_IAM
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

en el caso de mailgun:

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_USERNAME=miusuario@correo.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mipassword_en_mailgun
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Alguien ve algo raro? Bueno, ninguno está usando el puerto 587, que es el oficial para SMTP seguro.

- Google usa el 465, que la IANA tiene asignado oficialmente a otra cosa. Además, si bien el puerto 465 alguna vez se usó para SMTP seguro, entiendo que era usando TLS y no SSL
- Amazon ocupa el puerto 25 (originalmente para SMTP no seguro) y tls, lo cual no es un error. Desde hace años los servidores SMTP no dependen del puerto para establecer la seguridad. En cambio, le hacen honor al comando SMTP STARTTLS, que le hace un upgrade al handshake.
- Mailgun tiene encriptación null... eso sí es confuso, pero ocurre que eso se interpreta como: "no pongas la encriptación aquí, eso se negocia con STARTTLS y se hace más adelante en el handshake". De igual manera usan el puerto 2525, que oficialmente no es nada pero por costumbre, como el 587 está comunmente cerrado u ocupado, sirve de "mirror".

Lo importante es que modificar host, user y password no basta. Hay que hacer harta sintonía fina

Comment: Pero si en mi caso estoy intentando decirle al mismo Laravel, "mandame con las credenciales de Hostinger, un mail al correo de Hostinger" (osea exactamente al mismo). Estamos en la misma situación?

Comment: Lo más cómico es que si pongo credenciales de Gmail, funciona... Envía el correo de forma perfecta, pero no puedo decirle al cliente, "Mira capo, el correo de contacto hacia vos, te lo voy a enviar siempre yo", no es lo más profesional que digamos